# Heroku: How to connect the database through navicat

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-web-services

I have deploy a Helloworld django App on Heroku, and a shared database is generated ,My DATEBASE_URL is `postgres://sfbywaqhvj:_WgTgP660aDnYuS3aP3o@ec2-23-21-64-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com/sfbywaqhvj`
Can I connect the db through navicat or other local DBMS? THX

Comment: you mean `DATABASE_URL` when saying `DATEBASE_URL`?

Comment: Only need enable SSL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377118/heroku-database-connection-properties/17377446#17377446

Comment: you better remove the url of your db

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that's not a real Database URL you've posted and you're using the Heroku Shared 9.1 Beta addon (https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/ - which is the only shared DB that will let you connect externally you'd just split into the relevant parts

> postgres://sfbywaqhvj:_WgTgP660aDnYuS3aP3o@ec2-23-21-64-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com/sfbywaqhvj

becomes

```
Username: sfbywaqhvj
password: _WgTgP660aDnYuS3aP3o
host: ec2-23-21-64-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com
database: sfbywaqhvj
```

Comment: You also need to make sure that you're using SSL Mode = required.  To do this go into Connection Properties, select the SSL tab, enable "Use SLL" and select "required" from the SSL Mode dropdown

Comment: `heroku pg:credentials` will list this information broken down into the required parts.