# Heroku Database Connection Properties

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to perform a relatively trivial task: I want to connect to a Heroku database. I have created the database and have been issued credentials from the Heroku site. However, when I try to connect to this database using **anything** besides the terminal 'heroku' command line client, I get fatal errors or cannot connect errors.

The two tools that I tried to connect with outside of the Heroku terminal application are: Navicat and IntelliJ.

The error that I receive in Navicat when trying to connect to the database is:

```
could not connect to server: Host is down
    Is the server running on host "ec2-107-21-112-215.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My connection settings are as follows:

**Connection Name** Heroku Dev Test

**Host Name/IP Address** ec2-107-21-112-215.compute-1.amazonaws.com

**Port** 5432

Navicat doesn't even seem to be making an attempt to connect to that hostname.

When I try to connect with IntelliJ, using the full credentials, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "75.168.4.146", user "rphbqggxeokuxl", database "dc008iqk0rq4j5", SSL off
```

Again, I'm using the credentials that the Heroku application provides me with when accessing my database on their website.

Has anyone ran into this Heroku connection issue before?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Heroku provides this information for connecting from external sources:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress

The second error message indicates PostgreSQL is not configured to accept the connection you're trying to make. Given the information Heroku provides, a good guess is that you're not connecting with SSL. Try to enable that on your connection.

Here are instructions for using SSL with Navicat: http://mirror.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/navicat/rv_manual/ClientCert.html.

This may be helpful in configuring Intellij to use SSL: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely.

Comment: If you are configuring access from RubyMine, here is more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807272/configure-rubymine-remote-connection-to-heroku-postgresql

Comment: Here is how you configure it for DbVisualizer: http://bartling.blogspot.com/2013/06/connecting-dbvisualizer-to-heroku.html

Comment: Edit your Connection URL and add: `sslmode=require`.

Comment: enabling ssl fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 69):

I also had the issue with the `FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host` error message.

I solved the connection issue to my Heroku Postgres database by adding the following to my JDBC string: `&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`.

**Example**

```
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?user=username&password=secret&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

You will need the SSL option only if SSL is enabled for your Postgres database (which is the default).

**Hint**

If you want to check your database connection properties, then just run the following command with the [**Heroku Toolbelt**](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/): `heroku pg:info --app your-heroko-appname` (make sure that you have Postgres insalled to run this command in your terminal)

The `pg:info` command will also tell you that `sslmode` is set to `require`.

To test the database connection I recommend [SQL Power Architect](https://code.google.com/p/power-architect/) as it is the tool which I was using to check my solution.

Comment: `&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` adding this solved my problem. thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much #Benny. I was stuck from last two days and finally get resolved and I have also asked a question related to this on StackOverflow. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/50772559/7560986). You are most welcome on that also.

Comment: This helping me alot. Thank u :)

Comment: Since manually editing DATABASE_URL is not supported, the quickest way is to set PGSSLMODE=require in the environment variables.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47536752/152711

Comment: Why `NonValidatingFactory`? What are the security implications of not validating?

Comment: @jpmc26 I was asking myself the same questions. There definitely are security implications, however it seems that this is what Heroku is advising: https://help.heroku.com/S6LGZBIE/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-via-datagrip

Comment: This is what worked for me in 2021. Setting `sslmode=require` didn't work

Answer (score 22):

**IntelliJ -> Datasources and Drivers**

After you've configured the host, database and user details under the `General` tab switch to the `Advanced` tab and ensure that you've added the following:

- ssl = true
- sslfactory = org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
- sslmode = require

[image]

Comment: this works. The same properties apply in jetbrains DataGrip that i'm using.

Answer (score 14):

You may consider setting a ENVIRONMENT CONFIG VARIABLE 'PGSSLMODE' to 'require' via Heroku's web interface or CLI.

Case: Postgres dB set up as a Heroku add-on and attached to app on a Heroku Dyno.

Heroku's [instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases) unfortunately leave out any mention of how to activate SSL, even though it is required for any dB tier starting with Standard-0 by default.

Follow all of the pg-copy or pg-upgrade steps (preferred approach depends on your version of Postgres) in Heroku instructions; however, before decommissioning the old database (if relevant) -- add the PGSSLMODE environment variable.

The instructions sufficiently cover how to promote the new database (and, consequently set the DATABASE_URL), so *no changes/modifications to them* should be required.

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful!

Answer (score 11):

Wanted to help others who might run into this.
If you're supplying the Username and Password in seperate fields rather than on the command line, you need to use a ? between the database name and ssl=true and discard the first &

```
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

That's the command line that finally allowed me to connect to a PostgreSQL database using SQL Power Architect

Answer (score 9):

For those who might be using Spring Boot and having the configuration provided through the [DATABASE_URL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#spring-java) environment property (not system property), the suffix can be added to the property:

```
?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

and passed through with a slight modification to the config bean:

```java
@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException {

    URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
    String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
    String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];

    StringBuilder dbUrl = new StringBuilder(128);
    dbUrl.append("jdbc:postgresql://")
            .append(dbUri.getHost()).append(":")
            .append(dbUri.getPort())
            .append(dbUri.getPath());

    String query = dbUri.getQuery();
    if (null != query && !query.isEmpty()) {
        dbUrl.append("?").append(query);
    }

    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setUrl(dbUrl.toString());
    basicDataSource.setUsername(username);
    basicDataSource.setPassword(password);

    return basicDataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using node.js and was trying to run my knex migrations for my Heroku app. I tried appending `?sslmode=require` to the connection URL but it didn't work. I added `?ssl=true` instead and now it works perfectly.

Here's an example Heroku PostgreSQL connection URL that works:

`postgres://user:password@ec2-12-34-56-78.compute-99.amazonaws.com:port/databasename?ssl=true`

Answer (score 1):

Add or edit the following line in your postgresql.conf file :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Add the following line as the first line of pg_hba.conf. It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password:

```
TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD

host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Restart postgresql service:

```
net stop postgresql-9.0 & net start postgresql-9.0
```

(version should be based on your installation) -- On windows (run cmd as an administrator).

```
sudo service start postgresql -- On linux (or according to your linux distribution.)
```

Comment: how can u access postgresql.conf in heroku?

Comment: I actually don't remember since I am not using heroku since quite a time. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915865/how-to-access-postgresql-conf-file-of-postgresql-deployment-on-heroku)  if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.