# Configure RubyMine remote connection to Heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, jdbc, rubymine

How should I configure RubyMine jdbc datasource to remotely connect to Heroku's PostgreSQL database? Currently I am using such connection URL:

```
jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-197-241-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com/dbqi9t12t5035q
```

but I get error about lack of entry for host '62.87.242.2' in pg_hba.conf. I am pretty sure that user and password are correct, because it runs online... :-). Could you help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the Advanced tab, there are a bunch of properties.  Set the following properties:

```
ssl -> true
sslfactory -> org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Comment: I was having trouble connecting to any remotes, and this helped.

Comment: There was 3rd setting I've been missing in addition to the 2 above: `sslmode -> verify-ca`. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/how-to-connect-to-heroku-postgres.html

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing means the security policy of the Postgres server doesn't allow the connection.  Heroku Postgres only allow connections from within Heroku, as far as I know.

You'll need to use their official command line tools if you want to open a remote database connection:

```
heroku pg:psql
```

The official tools authenticate to Heroku and tunnel through their network.