# How to access postgresql.conf file of postgresql deployment on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, heroku

I have a Django app hosted on Heroku, with a postgresql DB, on a *Standard 0* plan. I want to access and read the `postgresql.conf` file for this particular app (to ascertain/edit the settings). Can anyone guide me how to do that?

*Note: I can't do that via the Heroku dashboard, and I don't know how to access the app's file structure over the Ubuntu commandline.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all current settings without an access to `postgres.conf`:

```
SELECT name, current_setting(name)
FROM pg_settings;

          name           |    current_setting    
-------------------------+-----------------------
 allow_system_table_mods | off
 application_name        | psql.bin
 archive_command         | (disabled)
 archive_mode            | off
 archive_timeout         | 0
...
```

You can also check which parameters are set in `postgres.conf` to values other than default:

```
SELECT name, current_setting(name), sourcefile, sourceline
FROM pg_settings
WHERE sourcefile notnull;

            name            |  current_setting  |               sourcefile               | sourceline 
----------------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+------------
 DateStyle                  | ISO, DMY          | /opt/postgres/9.5/data/postgresql.conf |        538
 default_text_search_config | pg_catalog.simple | /opt/postgres/9.5/data/postgresql.conf |        560
 dynamic_shared_memory_type | posix             | /opt/postgres/9.5/data/postgresql.conf |        130
...
```

Comment: Use [SET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) (of course you can change only the parameters you have write access to).

Comment: is there a way to set the parameters in heroku without running SET from your application on each request?