# Fail to connect AWS-Postgres server with spring boot application with heroku hosting

Tags: spring, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, heroku

I have host spring-boot application on Heroku and add Add-ons of Heroku-postgres. They provide me database credential which is hosted on AWS-EC2. I am trying to connect my spring boot application with that database which provided by Heroku and hosted on AWS-EC2 but I got an error as `no pg_hba.conf entry for host "49.34.151.37"`.

My POM.xml is as below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/
  maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring boot tomcat dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Google API Client -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Postgresql -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My application.properties file is as below

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-204-18-53.compute- 
1.amazonaws.com:5432/d695rcqcr9r06e&
user=poevxwkkkdcuho
&password=[password they provide]&sslmode=true
spring.datasource.username=poevxwkkkdcuho 
spring.datasource.password=[password they provide]
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

logging.level.org.org.springframework.retry=DEBUG
management.security.enabled=false
```

And error trace whihc i am getting is as below.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host 
 "49.34.151.37", user "poevxwkkkdcuho", database 
 "d695rcqcr9r06e&user=poevxwkkkdcuho&password=[password they provide]", SSL off
at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:348) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:271) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at com.loanguruhub.RestController.main(RestController.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
```

update:- I have check same application with local PostgreSQL server. It's works fine.

Comment: Is this somebody else's database?

Comment: The database is provided by Heroku...I have follow this link :-https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your JDBC driver to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The version `9.1-901-1.jdbc4` was released 7 years ago, and does not support the `sslmode` option.

Comment: I have make changes in pom.xml but it won't make any different in error.